# Limit central theorem - binominal distribution inequality ( Independant binominal Random variables )

Tags: binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

$$\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:X_n>\frac{pn^2}{2}\right)=?$$
When $p\in (0,1)$ , $\left\{X_n\right\}^{\infty }_{_{_{n=1}}}$,  $X_n~Bin\left(n,p\right)$, as they are independant of course.
What I tried is using as usual, like I do with normal, poi, and other stuff, the CLT.
There are two ways to do the solution:

1. divide the binomials to bernoli so we have $n\cdot n$ indexes and then use CLT with $n^2$.
2. keep the binominals, but we know the sum of binominal is a sum of their number of indexes.
   By trying both ways, I could not reach the answer.
   The way to answer those questions, is basically reach this ( it has always worked to me ):
   $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}-E\left[X_i\right]}{\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{n}}}<=a\right)\right)=\:\Phi \left(a\right)$$
   As the expression inside is basically $N(0,1)$.
   while trying to do, let us say the first way with $n^2$ indexes, I reach this:
   While $X_{i_j}~Ber(p)$
   $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }X_n>\frac{pn^2}{2}\right)=1-\lim _{n\to \infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }X_n\le \frac{pn^2}{2}\right)$$=$$1-\lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_{11}+..+X_{1n}+..X_{n1}+..+X_{nn}}{n^2}\le \:\frac{p}{2}\right)$$=$$1-\lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_{11}+..+X_{1n}+..X_{n1}+..+X_{nn}}{n^2}-p\le \:-\frac{p}{2}\right)$$=$$1-\lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\frac{X_{11}+..+X_{1n}+..X_{n1}+..+X_{nn}}{n^2}-p}{\frac{p\left(1-p\right)}{n}}\le \:\frac{-\frac{p}{2}}{\frac{p\left(1-p\right)}{n}}\right)$$
   =$$1-\lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\frac{X_{11}+..+X_{1n}+..X_{n1}+..+X_{nn}}{n^2}-p}{\frac{p\left(1-p\right)}{n}}\le \:-\frac{np}{2p\left(1-p\right)}\right)$$
   and here is the problem, The answer should be $$\Phi \left(-\sqrt{\frac{p}{2\left(1-p\right)}}\right)$$
   and if I do it by way 2 ( with $n$ indexes and not $n^2$, I receive ):
   $$1-\lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}-pn}{\frac{np\left(1-p\right)}{\sqrt{n}}}\le -\frac{p\sqrt{n}}{2\left(1-p\right)}\:\right)\:$$

Which is not the correct answer also.
What can be the problem? why is it not working?

Comment: CLT requires independence.

Comment: oh they are independant. I will edit, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_n = \sum _{i=1}^{n }\:X_i\sim B(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},p)$, we have
$$\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}(Y_n)=\frac{n(n+1)p}{2},\text{Var}(Y_n) = \frac{n(n+1)p(1-p)}{2}$$

The question you are asking is
$$\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n }\:X_i>\frac{pn^2}{2}\right) 
 =\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(Y_n>\frac{pn^2}{2}\right) \\
 =\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(Y_n-\frac{n(n+1)p}{2}>\frac{pn^2}{2}-\frac{n(n+1)p}{2}\right) \\
=\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{Y_n-\frac{n(n+1)p}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)p(1-p)}{2}}}>\frac{-\frac{np}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)p(1-p)}{2}}}\right) \\
=1-\Phi\left(\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\frac{-\frac{np}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)p(1-p)}{2}}}\right) 
=1-\Phi \left(-\sqrt{\frac{p}{2\left(1-p\right)}}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, Huge thanks. I think my professor did the same or something close.  
I think I might understood my mistake? I will update in a little :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I managed to understand and did it my way, a little long but awesome.